# How do I search a directory for all .XXX files and get a list of them in Perl?

Tags: perl, list, directory

I need to search in a directory for all the files that end in .123.

How do I (using Perl) get a list of those files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply:

```
@files = glob "$dirname/*.123";
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @files = grep { -f } glob '*.123';
```

Answer (score 1):

`glob` should do the job.
If you want to search recursively, you can use [`File::Find`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aFind).