# Searching for a valid pattern in files of under a folder? (Maybe with Perl or with some Apis at Java or anything else)

Tags: java, regex, perl, jsp, pattern-matching

I have a folder and it's name is `v3`. There are jsp files in that folder also in v3 folder there are some folders and there are jsp files in that folder too.

My jsp folders have some links as like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/main.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css<s:text name="scripts"/>/general_styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/v3/css<s:text name="scripts"/>/something.css" >
```

and scripts:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/static/scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts<s:text name="scripts"/>/prototype-1.6.0.2.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/scripts<s:text name="scripts"/>/${a.name}/<s:text name="genericJs"/>"></script>
```

For links:

`href` should start with `/static/` for example this is valid:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/main.css" type="text/css" />
```

For scripts:

`src` should start with `/static/` too for example this is valid:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/static/scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

What I want to do that I want to detect which files has `not valid` definitions.

**EDIT:** Valid - not valid is a notion for my company's system. We are moving our css and js folders to another and they will be under a folder and that folder's name is v3.

The program will work like that:

- `jsp` files are under v3 folder. I will run that program from anywhere and it will check all the jsp files under that folder(I will define the whole path of that v3 folder in the written program).
- It will find all lines that start with `<link` and `<script`.
- If it is `<link` it will find `href="`
- If it is `<script` it will find `src="`
- After it finds one of them it will check that does it start with `/static/` or not.
- If starts it is OK but if doesn't it will write the file name to output/text file or anything else.

Comment: You should rephrase your question. The relationship between the v3 folder and the /static links is not clear, I also don't get what should be valid / not valid. And do you want to achieve your goal with java, JS, EL, or JSP?

Comment: did any of these fine answers help you? are you still having problems?

Comment: @Joel I tested the answer that is written in Java and it works however I want to test the Perl ones too but couldn't yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, something like this will get you going:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Iterator<File> files = FileUtils.iterateFiles(new File("/path/to/v3"), new String[]{"jsp"}, true);
    while (files.hasNext()) {
        File jsp =  files.next();
        List<String> list = FileUtils.readLines(jsp);
        for (String line : list) {
            if(line.startsWith("<link") || line.startsWith("<script")) {
                if(!line.contains("/static")) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("invalid file found: " + jsp.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Edited to contain changes discussed in comments*

Comment: I am testing the code. Something more: StringUtils in under org.apache.commons.lang and the line FileUtils.readLines(jsp); should be surround with try catch. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: One more too. before if(!line.contains("/static")) there should be a control if (line.contains("src") || line.contains("href")). Because there are some valid situations as like writing script codes between <script type="text/javascript">  something to here </script> and it founds <script type="text/javascript"> as a not valid situation.

Comment: For recursion, use 
`FileUtils.iterateFiles(new File("/path/to/v3"), new String[]{"jsp"}, true);`.

Answer (score 1):

You might look into [`ack`](http://betterthangrep.com/), it is a Perl-based replacement for `grep` and should be able to do what you want.

Truthfully you don't want to do pattern matching on [xht]ml, you want to use a parser. A Perl script using [`HTML::TokeParser`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aTokeParser) can find all tags with certain attributes.

Here is a quick mock-up, though you may want some more useful output:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

use warnings;

use File::chdir;
use Cwd 'abs_path';

use HTML::TokeParser;

my @paths = @ARGV;
my @files;

foreach my $path (@paths) {
  local $CWD = $path;
  opendir( my $dh, $CWD);
  push @files, map { abs_path($_) } grep {/\.jsp$/} readdir $dh;
}

foreach my $file (@files) {
  my $parser = HTML::TokeParser->new($file);

  while (my $tag = $parser->get_tag("link", "script")) {

    if ($tag->[0] eq "link" and exists $tag->[1]{'href'}) {
      print "$file\n" unless $tag->[1]{'href'} =~ m#^/static/#;

    } elsif ($tag->[0] eq "script" and exists $tag->[1]{'src'}) {
      print "$file\n" unless $tag->[1]{'src'} =~ m#^/static/#;
    }

  }  

}
```

Comment: I didn't test the program left. Thanks for answer. Does it finds the jsp files under the folders of v3 too and how I will give the path as a parameter to program?

Comment: `perl program.pl path`. Perl puts all command line arguements in the array `@ARGV`.

Comment: I have updated the script to allow multiple paths on the command line. It will now also need the `File::chdir` module (available through `cpan`)

Answer (score 1):

Use [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/~jfearn/HTML-Tree-4.1/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder.pm) (and thus [HTML::Element](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::Element)) and look_down to find your stuff.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.012;

use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my @filelist = @ARGV; ### or some other method ofc.

for my $file (@filelist) {
  my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_file($file)->elementify;
  for my $e ( $tree->look_down( '_tag' => 'link',
                                sub { !($_[0]->attr('href') =~ |^/static/|) }
                              ) 
            ) {
    say "$file: ", $e->as_HTML;
  }
}
```

It's also then pretty trivial to modify your HTML with the same script (ie, concatenate '/static/' to the front of the bad attributes -- `$e->attr('href') = '/static/' . $e->attr('href')`) and spit it back out with [HTML::Tidy](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::Tidy) with `HTML::Tidy->new->clean($tree->as_HTML)`.

Edit: Re your question about the file list, assigning ARGV to the file list was done simply because it was tangential to the question. See [How do I search a directory for all .XXX files and get a list of them in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300825/how-do-i-search-a-directory-for-all-xxx-files-and-get-a-list-of-them-in-perl) for example. I'd use [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Find):

```
use File::Find;
my @rootdirs = @ARGV or die "Please pass all root directories to search as arguments!";
my @filelist = find( sub { /\.jsp$/ or return; }, @rootdirs );
```

That would recurse through your starting directories (passed by argument -- you could also assign them directly to @rootdirs if you prefer) and give you all the .jsp files in them as items in @filelist.

Comment: I didn't test the program left. Thanks for answer too. I will ask the same question, does it finds the jsp files under the folders of v3 too and how I will give the path as a parameter to program?